# Firebase real time database posts

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm working on a social media app, and I want to upload a post to firebase, but it won't show up on the real time database

```
let DB_BASE =  Database.database().reference()
private var _REF_NOW = DB_BASE.child("now").childByAutoId()

var REF_NOW: DatabaseReference {
    return _REF_NOW
}

func uploadPost(withTitle title: String, forUID uid: String,
                withDescription description: String, sendComplete: @escaping (_ status:
    Bool) -> ()) {
    REF_NOW.childByAutoId().updateChildValues(["Title": title, "Id": uid,
                                               "Description": description])
    sendComplete(true)
}

@IBAction func postPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    if textfield.text != nil && textview.text != nil && textview.text != ""
    {
        postBtn.isEnabled = false
        DataService.instance.uploadPost(withTitle: textfield.text!, forUID:
        (Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!, withDescription: textview.text) {
            (isComplete) in
            if isComplete {
                self.postBtn.isEnabled = true
                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            } else {
                self.postBtn.isEnabled = true
                print("There was an error!")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `childByAutoId` is duplicated and try using `setValue` instead of `updateChildValues`.

```
private var _REF_NOW = DB_BASE.child("now")

REF_NOW.childByAutoId().setValue(["Title": title, "Id": uid, 
"Description": description])
```

Comment: it didn't work it's giving me: setValue: or removeValue: at /now/-LHpftdYz6dKVslftJrN failed: permission_denied

Comment: How about changing the database rule to {
 "rules": {
  ".read": true,
  ".write": true
 }
} for develop purpose